# facebook login sample app show nothing?

Tags: android, facebook

i follow this turtorial 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

but after that My app just show fb login button , when click in that button , it show a pop up

https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/851562_459469690794167_1039002331_n.png

and when click ok it show nothing else

Comment: then procedure with ok.. and have a head start..

Comment: I mean if login success my onSessionStateChange will print" Logged in..."
but in my case it doesn't . It show nothing , it means that logging in is not success and i dont't know why

Comment: then you are correct..

Comment: code is correct but i still cannot login to face book . I put a nother button and set it invisible then i modify onSessionStateChange () method like this if (state.isOpened()) {
   shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  } else if (state.isClosed()) {
   shareButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
but when i click login , button still not visible . It means that state is close and i cannot login . Where is my error?

Comment: Are there any errors in logcat? Is your Session.StatusCallback being called? Did you try stepping through it in the debugger? What about the "exception" variable that's passed to the callback? Try printing that out.

Comment: Thank for your reply .
here is my onSessionStateChange function :
 private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
  Exception exception) {
  if (state.isOpened()) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
  } else if (state.isClosed()) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
  }
  }
And log cat show

12-17 10:38:41.464: I/MainFragment(9886): Logged out...
12-17 10:38:41.488: W/EGL_emulation(9886): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-17 10:38:41.516: I/MainFragment(9886): Logged out...

with no exception .

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Did u get the solution??